# Looking for a MVVM example

Tags: mvvm

Are there complete MVVM example solutions that don't use a 3rd party frameworks, Silverlight, or WPF??  Maybe something with WSF?  -- thanks

Comment: MVVM was designed specifically for Silverlight/WPF, so I doubt you'll find many examples which use neither.

Comment: wsf? it stands for ? windows script file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a "clean" example on MVVM (no framework attached), I suggest looking at https://github.com/brentedwards/Movies

This is a project by Brent Edwards wich is used on his presentation: WPF with MVVM from the trenches.

There is also a video in wich Brent gives some of the hightights of this presentation on [DNR TV Episode 184: WPF with MVVM from the trenches with Brent Edwards](http://dnrtv.com/defaut.aspx?ShowID=184)

If you're looking a no-wpf and no-sl implmentation, you should be looking for the [Presentation pattern from Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) wich is the generic definition of the pattern.